# How Can I Put A 2d Image Into The Side Viewport? | Maya 2016

Tags: images, 3d, maya, modeling

I'm a student who is very new to Maya, and I am wondering how to put an image into the side viewport to allow me to turn 2d objects into 3d objects.

I used to to this exact same thing in Cinema 4d, but everything was a lot easier, and I felt limited when trying to model guns, cars, and tools.

At first I tried dragging an image into the viewport, it brought up a sketchy program called "FCheck" (I believe it is a part of Maya).

I looked at a video when someone modeled a Karambit, they just-so-happened to skip the part in the video where they add the image to the viewport. If I knew what it was called in Maya to add an image, I could have possibly found the answer on Google. But, I had no clue what it was called. I've only watched a one hour video on YouTube for Maya's tools, so I'm fresh into Maya.

Comment: Hello Ven and welcome to GraphicDesign! What have you tried? What resources have you looked at?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as off-topic, since 3D questions like this are not in scope anymore..

Comment: Hi VenHayz, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your question. 3D Questions are a strange fit here: they aren't off-topic *per se*, but we have very little expertise among us to give good answers. There is a proposal for a 3D StackExchange site that could use your support: [3D Computer Graphics](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/86368/3d-computer-graphics). If you have questions about GD.SE, have a look at the [help] or feel free to join us in [chat] once your reputation allows you to (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score -1):

Within the viewport is a menu bar at the top. Click on View -> Image Plane -> Import Image. There, select your image and when done, it will place a 3d version of your 2d image. (Not exactly as I wanted, but will possibly work)

Comment: Sometimes importing an image (especially high res) while on perspective view causes bugs for me. You might need to switch to orthographic view and then import the image